# How to convert pivot queryfrom SQL Server to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I am migrating SQL Server procedure to PostgreSQL and I could not convert this part query. How to convert this SQL SERVER query to Postgres?

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Datepart(mm, createdatetime) AS mm,
               createdatetime,
               'test'                       AS OcwStatisticsGubun
        FROM   tdoor WITH(nolock)
        WHERE  deleteyesno = 'N'
               AND Year(createdatetime) = 2020
               AND isopen != 0) A
       PIVOT ( Count(createdatetime)
             FOR mm IN ([01],
                        [02],
                        [03],
                        [04],
                        [05],
                        [06],
                        [07],
                        [08],
                        [09],
                        [10],
                        [11],
                        [12]) ) AS pv
```

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from crosstab('select ''test'' as OcwStatisticsGubun , 
                                          extract(month from CreateDateTime) ::int , 
                                          count(extract(month from CreateDateTime))::int as cnt from tdoor t 
                       where extract(year from CreateDateTime) = 2020 and DeleteYesNo = ''N'' AND IsOpen != 0
                       group by extract(month from CreateDateTime)::int order by 2'
                      ,$$values ('1'::int),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('10'),('11'),('12')$$
                      )
                       as cnt(OcwStatisticsGubun text, "1" int,"2" int ,"3" int ,"4" int, "5" int, "6" int,
                              "7" int,"8" int ,"9" int ,"10" int, "11" int, "12" int)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).